# Is there any way to show only year using the textbox?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap datepicker,but it show date,month and year i want show year only in datepicker in textbox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker to show year only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528623/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-year-only)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: " yyyy",  //see there is extra space in format, dont remove it
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

use this :

```
<html lang="en">

<head>


    <title>Bootstrap - year picker only example</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


</head>

<body>


<div class="container text-center">


     <h2>Bootstrap - year picker only example</h2>

     <input class="date-own form-control" style="width: 300px;" type="text">


  <script type="text/javascript">

      $('.date-own').datepicker({

         minViewMode: 2,

         format: 'yyyy'

       });

  </script>


</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: already i tried 
here my code

      <input class="form-control datepicker" id="yearofpub" name="yearofpub" type="text"> 

$("#yearofpub").datepicker
  ({
     format: " yyyy", 
      viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
   });

but not working i want only year

Comment: i used datepicker  multiple place in my application this  same bootstrap datepicker plugin ,if any solution are  there in jquery show only year in particular textbox

Comment: change the ID or class for each box where you used datepicker and then define their format using their ID or Class .