# How can I change my date picker into a year only picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change to year picker calendar only in a dynamic input fields.The calender should show only year values Can any one help me please.

Here is the javascript code.

```
$('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){

    if( $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker') === false )  {
        $(this).datepicker();
    }

});
```

Comment: which datepicker library are you using ?

Comment: The date picker would be a massive overhead for this task. Simply make a drop down with a list of numbers from year 19xx to 20xx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528623/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-year-only

Comment: its like,it works very well but it displays dates, month, and year calendar.but for me i wanted to display years only.i will be so glad when you help me on that please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI DatePicker to show year only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528623/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-year-only)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one. And see if it will help your problem.

HTML:

```
<select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>
```

JS:

```
var startYear = 1800;
for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > startYear; i--)
{
  $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/hvmbqsdL/)

Answer (score 2):

```js
 $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker') === false )  {
        $(this).datepicker({
            minViewMode: 2,
            format: 'yyyy'
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

I assume it is bootstrap datepicker ([Link](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html))

Comment: It has failed to work.when i comment out the date format,then it brings calender including months,dates and year.when i live the year format,it doesn't work.please help me

Comment: @n.ssendawula you can find the running example above in my post.

Comment: your code is run very well in a separate file but when i paste it in my script,it doesn't. how can i make it work?what may be the cause of such a failure.i need some help

Comment: Thanks a lot. now it works fine.i have solved the problem.have a nice day

Comment: I want to help me with something,how can i set the maximum year to the current year.thanks

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you, and post new question for this new doubt, along with what you have done till now to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a `datepicker` if you want to **select a year only**. Use a `select` for that. However, you can modifiy the `datepicker` (since you didn't mention which one you are using I assume **jQuery UI**) to only **return the year**.

**Have a look at this fiddle:**

```js
$(function() { 
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy' });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>
```