# Changing Jquery UI Datepicker Css by ID

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently trying to customize a datepicker to only show Month and Year selectors but I want to only have that CSS hidden for a specific Datepicker. I am currently trying to dictate a specific picker by ID and I do not know if what I am doing is possible or if I am just doing it wrong. Below is the input I am using as well as the Css code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#QuarterYearPicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: '1950:2013', // Optional Year Range
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 0, 1));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#QuarterYearPicker.ui-datepicker-calendar,
.ui-datepicker-month {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div>Pick the Year from which you want to grab data from: <input id="QuarterYearPicker" readonly /></div>
```

I am only trying to get this specific Datepicker to display the drop down for year and show nothing else.

Comment: Remove the comma.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528623/jquery-ui-datepicker-to-show-year-only

Comment: Why use a jQuery Datepicker just to select a year? Just use a dropdown list.

Comment: That is similar to what I have I just need to be able to change the Css on a specific Datepicker. I am using more than one and I do not want the CSS changed on all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why using a jQuery datepicker that will anyways show you a `select` box with a years range?

```js
var startYear = 1950;
var endYear = new Date().getFullYear(); // or hardcode 2013 here
var optionsYears = "";
while(endYear >= startYear) optionsYears += "<option>"+ (endYear--) +"</option>";

$("#year").append(optionsYears);
```

```html
Pick a year <select id="year"></select>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Technically, the following code will do what you want... for now. It uses an undocumented feature of the `inst` argument passed to the `beforeShow` event handler. That feature, the `dpDiv` property, is a jQuery object that references the calendar drop-down element specific to that Datepicker instance.

I would suggest using a different method (like creating a unique control that is specific to this use case) as there is no guarantee future versions of jQuery UI will support this property.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#QuarterYearPicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    yearRange: '1950:2013', // Optional Year Range
    dateFormat: 'yy',
    beforeShow: function(el, inst) {
      inst.dpDiv.addClass("datepicker-" + el.id);
    },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
      var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, 0, 1));
    }
  });
  $('#OtherYearPicker').datepicker();
});
```

```css
.datepicker-QuarterYearPicker .ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div>Pick the Year from which you want to grab data from: <input id="QuarterYearPicker" readonly /></div>

<div>Pick the Year from which you want to grab data from: <input id="OtherYearPicker" readonly /></div>
```